# Quando utilizar map() e filter() em Python?

Tags: python

Tenho uma dúvida em relação às funções `map` e `filter`.

Por exemplo, dado este código:

```
numeros = list(map(lambda x: x-1 , [2, 3, 4, 5]))
print(numbers)
Output:
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Aqui neste exemplo poderia utilizar a função `filter` e obter mesmo output?

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
numeros_pares = list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, lista))
print(numeros_pares)
Output:
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

E aqui poderia usar a função `map` e obter o mesmo output?

O meu objectivo era perceber onde posso usar o `map` ou `filter`.

Comment: O `map` transforma cada elemento da lista em outro - inclusive, o resultado não precisa ser do mesmo tipo da entrada (o lambda poderia retornar string ou qualquer outra coisa). Já o `filter` não transforma nada, ele sempre seleciona dentre os elementos da lista, os que satisfazem o critério (que no seu caso, é "o número deve ser par").

Answer (score 4):

A função `map` mapeia; enquanto a `filter` filtra. Não são equivalentes e nunca uma substituirá a outra. Na verdade é bastante comum utilizá-las em conjunto (as operações de mapear e filtrar, não necessariamente as funções).

A função `map` garante que sempre existirá um resultado para cada valor de entrada. Estritamente falando podemos afirmar que o comprimento da sequência resultado de um mapeamento será sempre igual ao da sequência mapeada.

Veja que no seu exemplo você mapeou a sequência `[2, 3, 4, 5]` e gerou a `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. Cada elemento da entrada gerou um valor na saída.

Mesmo que aplique uma função que não possua explicitamente um retorno durante o mapeamento será gerado na saída um valor `None` respectivo:

```py
def pares(x):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        return x

print(list(map(pares, range(10))))
# [0, None, 2, None, 4, None, 6, None, 8, None]
```

Já a função `filter` tem por objetivo reduzir a sequência de entrada com base nas condições definidas pelo filtro. Não é garantido que sempre a sequência gerada seja menor que a sequência original pois existe o caso de todos os elementos satisfazerem a condição do filtro, mas é certo que nunca a sequência será maior que a sequência original. Existe ainda a certeza que todos os valores da sequência gerada pertencem, também, a sequência original. Isto é, se `filter(A)` produz `B`, então a interseção de `A` com `B` sempre será `B`.

Isso pode ser observado quando você aplica um filtro na sequência `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` com o objetivo de buscar apenas os números pares, obtendo `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]`.

Na verdade, tanto `map` quanto `filter` são classes e, portanto, não são basicamente chamadas de funções, mas sim instanciações das respectivas classes. Ambas as instâncias são objetos iteráveis que produzirão os valores da sequência final quando consumidas por demanda. Isto é, a sequência resultado não é armazenada em memória, mas sim produzida elemento a elemento quando é iterada (por isso o retorno é convertido para uma `list` antes de exibir).

Sobre utilizá-las em conjunto, imagine uma sequência de usuários com os campos `email` e `ativo`.

```py
users = [
  ('felix@servidor', True),
  ('caitie@servidor', True),
  ('joel@servidor', False),
  ('violet@servidor', False),
  ('traci@servidor', True)
]
```

O objetivo é obter a lista de e-mail somente dos usuários ativos.

Com a `map` podemos extrair a informação do e-mail e retornar uma lista com essa informação:

```
def get_email(user):
  return user[0]

print(list(map(get_email, users)))
# ['felix@servidor', 'caitie@servidor', 'joel@servidor', 'violet@servidor', 'traci@servidor']
```

Mas não queremos todos os e-mails. Então utilizamos a `filter` para obter apenas aqueles ativos:

```py
def is_active(user):
  return user[1] == True

print(list(filter(is_active, users)))
# [('felix@servidor', True), ('caitie@servidor', True), ('traci@servidor', True)]
```

Mas não queremos todas as informações, apenas o e-mail. Então unimos as duas:

```
emails = map(get_email, filter(is_active, users))
print(list(emails))
# ['felix@servidor', 'caitie@servidor', 'traci@servidor']
```

Mas isso dificilmente é utilizado na prática por não ser um código fácil de ler, enquanto se utilizar a *list comprehension* fica bem mais fácil e produz o mesmo resultado:

```
emails = [get_email(user) for user in users if is_active(user)]
print(emails)
# ['felix@servidor', 'caitie@servidor', 'traci@servidor']
```

A parte `get_email(user)` faz o papel de mapeamento enquanto a `if is_ative(user)` faz o filtro.

---

Se fosse traduzir o comportamento de ambas em uma função puramente em Python, teríamos a função `map`:

```py
def map(function, *iterables):
  for values in zip(iterables):
    yield function(*values)
```

Enquanto a função `filter` seria:

```py
def filter(function, iterable):
  for value in iterable:
    if function(value):
      yield value
```

Em resumo:

- `map` você controla **qual** será o valor retornado, mas **não quando** será retornado (sempre retorna alguma coisa);
- `filter` você controla **quando** será retornado, mas **não qual** será o valor retornado (sempre retorna o valor original);

Comment: resposta grande, eusó daria mais ênfase, porque considero mais importante: para a sintaxe de "comprehensions", que está escondidinha no final. já que  o código fica mais curto, (e, dependendo da operação, mais eficiente) . Dá pra falar um pouco do "reduce" também - que junto com os outros dois fazem o tripe "filter, map, reduce" pra operações com dados - e que, ao contrário de map e filter, nao tem uma forma simples de ser feito com as comprehensions.

Comment: @jsbueno verei se consigo encaixar as sugestões. Obrigado.