# Utilizando recursos de programação funcional para remover uma lista de palavras de outra lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, programação-funcional

Estou fazendo a análise de um texto literário e estou tendo o seguinte problema para remover um grupo de palavras do texto. Nâo são palavras repetidas. link_words são palavras que vão atrapalhar uma posterior análise do texto, por isso quero retirá-las. Os conjuntos abaixo são meramente ilustrativos!

```
link_words = ["for","on","this","will","do","did","have","has","my","the","as","be","he"]

words = ["for","on","this","will","do","did","have","has","my","the","as","be","he","virus"]
```

A ideia é aplicar `map()` e `filter()` de forma a que eu remova da lista `words` as palavras contidas em `link_words`. Peguei um conjunto menor para facilitar. A saída deveria ser

```
["virus"]
```

Aplica o filtro:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x in link_words,words))
```

cuja saída está correta:

```
["for","on","this","will","do","did","have","has","my","the","as","be","he"]
```

Tentei fazer o seguinte depois:

seja `filtro = filter(lambda x: x in link_words,words)`

Não estou conseguindo chegar ao resultado esperado com

```
 list(map(lambda  x: words.remove(x),filtro))
```

O que eu errei? Como corrigir o map?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Remover elementos repetidos usando duas listas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/443192/remover-elementos-repetidos-usando-duas-listas)

Comment: Não precisa de map e filter, a pergunta sugerida acima tem uma solução pro seu caso

Comment: @hkotsubo  eu gostaria de aprender a usá-los! poderia me ajudar a achar o erro?

Comment: @hkotsubo Na verdade nao sao palavras repetidas mas um grupo de palavras que quero retirar do texto para analisá-lo sem elas!

Comment: Não se prenda ao título da pergunta, leia as respostas que tem  lá, pois o problema é o mesmo (remover de uma lista os elementos que estão em outra)

Comment: De qq forma, `map` serve para transformar os elementos da lista em outra coisa, então o `lambda` deve retornar alguma coisa. Só que `remove` não retorna nada, então o resultado vai ser uma lista cheia de `None`. Eu acho que map/filter não são a melhor solução pra esse caso

Comment: @hkotsubo concordo mas eu gostaria de aplicar map e filter!

Comment: @hkotsubo O objetivo é mais aprender a usar map e filter, embora possa nao ser a melhor abordagem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) serve para transformar os elementos da lista em outra coisa e no seu caso não tem o que transformar, pois você só quer filtrar.

Como você quer todos os elementos de uma lista que não estão em outra, bastaria fazer:

```
filtrados = list(filter(lambda x: x not in link_words,words))
```

Ou seja, os elementos de `words` que não estão em `link_words`.

Não tem porque usar `map`, pois os elementos não são alterados. `map` só faz sentido se você quer gerar outros valores diferentes da lista original. Por exemplo:

```
lista = [1, 2, 3]
# gera outra lista, contendo o dobro de cada elemento
dobros = list(map(lambda x: x * 2, lista))
print(dobros) # [2, 4, 6]
```

Usei `map` para gerar outra lista, contendo o dobro de cada número da lista original.

Mas no seu caso você não está modificando os valores da lista (no sentido de transformá-los em outros valores), você só está filtrando (escolhendo quais você quer e quais você não quer), então **não faz sentido** usar `map` nesse caso.

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/443793/112052) até dá um exemplo que usa `map`, mas ela faz coisas absolutamente desnecessárias, como por exemplo criar um array de booleanos, e depois usa `index` para cada elemento da lista, o que torna o algoritmo bem ineficiente, pois a lista será percorrida várias vezes, já que [`index` faz uma busca linear para encontrar o índice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5913745). É uma volta desnecessária somente para "forçar" o uso de um recurso (tanto que ela reconhece no final que existe uma solução melhor, sem precisar de `map`).

Ou seja, só porque é possível usar `map`, não quer dizer que você deva fazê-lo. Você não deve forçar o uso de um recurso para resolver um problema, você deve avaliar o problema e ver qual recurso é o mais adequado. E usar `map` não é necessário nesse caso.

Veja mais sobre isso [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/414322/112052), que inclusive dá alguns exemplos em que faz sentido  usar `map` e `filter`.

Veja também outras soluções para o seu caso (que nem precisaria de [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) também) [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/443431/112052).

Answer (score 2):

**O Erro**

A linha `list(map(lambda  x: words.remove(x),filtro))` está retornando

```
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

(que não é a resposta esperada) porque `words.remove(x)` retorna `None`. Por exemplo, se você define

```
words = ["for","on","this","will","do","did","have","has","my","the","as","be","he","virus"]
```

e usa o método `remove`, você terá

```
>> words.remove("for")
>> words
["on","this","will","do","did","have","has","my","the","as","be","he","virus"]
```

mas se você fizer

```
>> new_words = words.remove("for")
>> new_words
None
```

**Uma possível resposta usando `map` e `filter`**

Ao invés disso você pode fazer

```
words_in_link = list(map(lambda x: x not in link_words, words))
list(filter(lambda x: words_in_link[words.index(x)], words))
```

que retornará

```
['virus']
```

*Explicação:*

`words_in_link` será uma lista com `Trues` se a string da lista `words` correspondente não estiver em `link_words` e `False` se estiver.

```
>> print(words)
['for', 'on', 'this', 'will', 'do', 'did', 'have', 'has', 'my', 'the', 'as', 'be', 'he', 'virus']
>> print(words_in_link)
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True]
```

então você usa o `filter` como

```
list(filter(lambda x: words_in_link[words.index(x)], words))
```

que vai selecionar apenas as strings de `words` que não estão em `link_words`.

**Uma resposta melhor, só usando `filter`**

Não há necessidade de usar `filter` e `map` para resolver esse problema, você também pode fazer

```
list(filter(lambda x: x not in link_words, words))
```

que retornará

```
['virus']
```